# (OpenShift) Permission denied when installing my own cartridge from my github repository

Tags: mysql, openshift

I froked MySQL cartridge from official github repo and I added some modifications to support utf8mb4 encoding.
this is my cartiridge on github : https://github.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4

When I want to add this cartridge to my scalable php app using the openshift web admin panel by providing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4/master/metadata/manifest.yml. I get this error :

```
Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 54474a6a500446ad2d0000ac -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon  
'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c230' /bin/sh -c 
\"/var/lib/openshift/54474a6a500446ad2d0000ac/mysql-utf8mb4/bin/setup --version 
5.5\""' returned an error. rc=126
/bin/sh: /var/lib/openshift/54474a6a500446ad2d0000ac/mysql-utf8mb4/bin/setup: Permission denied
```

I don't know what's wrong, can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of mysql-utf8mb4/bin/setup? Its most likely trying to run something as root which of course isn't allowed on the system.

Comment: I created my own cartridge of mysql supporting utf8mb4, you can use it if you want : https://github.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: @amgohan i am a newbie on openshift, how to use your cartridge ? i mean a commandline step by step, would you like to update your readme.md on your github ?

Comment: @fawwaz : go to your application on openshift web gui, click "on see the list of cartridges you can add", after that go to the bottom of the page "Install your own cartridge" then copy past this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4/master/metadata/manifest.yml in the input text, then click next, next ...

Comment: I did it and it prompt an error say like this : "The cartridge manifest at 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4/master/metadata/manifest.yml' was not available (status code: 503)." Whats wrong ? @amgohan

Comment: okay, it works, after retrying several times it works

Comment: Anyway, i can't add phpmyadmin cartridge after adding your cartridge. How to make phpmyadmin cartridge works with your catridge ? @amgohan